# There is another cms for django?(not "django CMS") or why i should use django cms?

Tags: django, web, django-cms

I was trying to create Django-based templates, which I found after a bit of searching on the Django CMS site. But then I went to install it and figure out how to make a template for it, I just realized
Just installing Django CMS is difficult for the simple user, but even for me, the programmer, it is difficult to install. Is there no substitute for it? Or how can I make it easier for my users to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is a generic web software framework; trying to compare it in itself to WordPress is quite apples-to-oranges.

[Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/), which you've found, is one CMS application for Django. [Wagtail](https://wagtail.org/) is another popular one. ([There are a bunch more.](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/cms/)
It's also not unheard of for someone to roll their own CMS on top of Django.)